# Infinite loop while traversing XML in Actionscript 3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, traversal, infinite-loop

I've narrowed down the code to this (ignore the colourization):

```
var theXML:XML = 
    <xml>
        word
    </xml>;

for each (var i:XML in theXML.*) {
    trace(i);
}
```

For some reason, this prints out "word" over and over indefinitely. Any thoughts as to why? I'm a bit out of practice and have a feeling it's something obvious, but I'm stumped.

Thanks,
Cameron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding it interesting I just tested. The result is just **one single** "word", as expected.

Probably you have placed it into an ENTER_FRAME/TIMER event handler or eventually on a frame on the timeline that gets looped.

Comment: Argh, you're right, the function it's in is being called over and over for some reason. I feel so silly! Thanks a lot!

Comment: No P, it's always the most obvious things you don't see.